# MVVM Flutter approach when there is a condition to display a view

Tags: flutter, mvvm

Currently I have NonMVVM pattern like this,

and I'm trying to adapt to MVVM pattern, but I cant wrap my brain around how to properly approach this.

If I have a condition for my views, should I keep it inside the views class, or should I move this into viewModel class?

```
  Container(

    child: PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (int page) {
        setState(() {
          pageIndex = page;
          switch (pageIndex) {
            case 0:
              pageTitle = 'Home Page';
              break;
            case 1:
              pageTitle = 'User Page';
              break;
            case 2:
              pageTitle = 'Announcement Page';
              break;
            default:
              pageTitle = '';
          }
        });
      },
      children:
          (userLoggedIn)
              ? <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child:  HomePage(),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: UserPage(),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: AnnouncementPage(),
                  ),
                ]
              : <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child:  HomePage(),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: AnnouncementPage(),
                  ),
                ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use state management techniques like:

> Provider, or
> GetX

Comment: I actually am, I'm using Stacked. but question here is if I have a condition(s) for my view is it considered a business logic? should it be seperated into viewModel?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).